# Distribution of $X_1X_2+X_3X_4$

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ be independent $N(0,1)$. Find the distribution of $Y= X_1X_2+X_3X_4$

I am having difficulty in solving this question or atleast how to approach it.